# 2 Collection View in one View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have this StoryBoard: 
[image]
and this code in MainViewControler:

```
class TipViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

    let tips = ["Jakość frytek nas nie zadawala", "Kolor frytek jest niesatysfakcjonujący", "LOT i reklamacja", "Olej nie spełnia naszych oczekiwań", "jakiś fajny"]

    let tipsImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "a1.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "a2.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "a3.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "a4.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "a5.jpg")!]

    let leaflets = ["AV-AddedValueFries-Ulotka", "AV-AddedValueFries-Ulotka 23112", "Ulotka", "Fajna ulotka"]

    let leafletsImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "d1.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "d2.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "d3.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "d4.jpg")!]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView1.dataSource = self
        collectionView1.delegate = self
        collectionView2.dataSource = self
        collectionView2.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tips.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
        cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

CellVC1:

```
class TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets: UICollectionViewCell {
    // Outtlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel1: UILabel!

}
```

CellVC2:

```
class TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets: UICollectionViewCell {
    // Outtlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel2: UILabel!

}
```

I have problem with:
1. in line:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
        cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]
```

I have error: "Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'titleLabel'" and "Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imgView'"

2. How can I display data in the second CollectionView (collectionView2)?

**UPDATE 1**

WIth this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == collectionView1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellTips
            cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
            cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
            cell.titleLabel2.text = leaflets[indexPath.item]
            cell.imgView2.image = leafletsImages[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with compilation. 
Now problem is in this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tips.count
    }
```

Comment: try my answer func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if collectionView == collectionView1{
        return tips.count
    }else{
        return leaflets.count
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your numberOfItem method to :-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if collectionView == collectionView1{
        return tips.count
    }else{
        return leaflets.count
}
```

Change your cellForItemAt method to :-

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           Var cell = UICollectionViewCell()  
    if collectionView == collectionView1{
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
    }else{
       cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
    }
   cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
   cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]

    return cell
             }
```

Comment: this will give error that cell is not accessible , if vars are local scope

Comment: scope of the cell is local to the method. and the variable will be accessible in the cellForItemAt method.

Comment: cell scope is bounded with If statement and there is error in picking the right collectionView, UICollectionViewCell is not convertible to TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets. This code even won't compile

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 if collectionView == collectionView1 {

        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1 identifier", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellTips
        cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
        cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]

     // set other properties

        return cell
 } else {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2 identifier", for: indexPath) as! TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
      cell.titleLabel.text = tips[indexPath.item]
     cell.imgView.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]

     // set other properties
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Ok, I add UPDATE 1 to my first post. Can you check?

Comment: for `TipCollectionViewCellTips` cell identifier must be `Cell1` and for `TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets` cell identifier must be `Cell2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

         if collectionView == collectionView1 {
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as TipCollectionViewCellTips
             cell.titleLabel1.text = tips[indexPath.item]
             cell.imgView1.image = tipsImages[indexPath.item]
             return cell
         }
         else {
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
             cell.titleLabel2.text = leaflets[indexPath.item]
             cell.imgView2.image = leafletsImages[indexPath.item]
             return cell
    }
}
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

> > Change this linke into

```
 let cell = collectionView1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
```

> > to

```
let cell = collectionView1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as TipCollectionViewCellLeaflets
```